# System.TimeZoneInfo does not contain a definition for FindSystemTimeZoneId in Metro Style Apps

Tags: timezone, styles, microsoft-metro

System.TimeZoneInfo does not contain a definition for FindSystemTimeZoneId , then how get the current time from other country TimeZone in Metro style apps.

In TimeZoneInfo class has Local and Utc properties, Equals, ReferenceEquals and  ConvertTime methods only..

Comment: This is just one of many restrictions in the WinRT api.  This specific limitation is caused by Metro apps no longer having access to the registry.  You'll have to learn to live without it.  Consider some kind of web service to get the info you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Date and Time from specific TimeZone in metro style apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942137/how-to-get-date-and-time-from-specific-timezone-in-metro-style-apps)